# Why does this program crashes everytime?

Tags: assembly, x86, mean, masm, irvine32

Title: Question 5

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
x dword ?
y dword ?
z dword ?

.code

Main PROC

Call ReadInt
Mov eax, x
Add eax, y
Add eax, z
Mov ebx, 3
div ebx


call Dumpregs
call crlf

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `DIV` also affects `EDX`, which is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you've provided it's difficult to say.

One likely cause of crashes is that you're not clearing `edx` prior to the division. If you read the description for `DIV` in [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) you'll see that `div r/m32` actually uses the 64-bit register pair `edx:eax` as the dividend. If `edx` happens to contain some arbitrary value, you run the chance of getting a quotient that won't fit in 32 bits, which will cause an exception.

Hence, you'll typically want to clear `edx` prior to each `div`. That can be done with `mov edx,0` or `xor edx,edx`.